# Ideal number of Rabbit MQ connection in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq

I'm trying to apply RabbitMQ for my node.js/express app as a task queue.

Something I confused is the ideal number of connection.
Some guide that I found is only have one connection is ideal because node.js is single thread. And the other guide I found is separate connections to publish and consume.

I want to know which is best practice.

1. Use separate connections to publish and consume (So two connections)
2. Share single connection for both publisher and consumer

As I mentioned, the purpose of rabbitmq is task queue.

Thanks in advance.